# Reading and writing from/to ttyS0

Tags: c, linux, usb, posix, uart

I have a RPI Zero W connected to my virtual machine through USB, which can be found under /dev/ttyS0 on both PC and the RPI. Currently I am trying to send something from the RPI through the USB cable to the virtual machine (PC).

I am trying to read on the port with the following code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>   /* Standard input/output definitions */    
    #include <string.h>  /* String function definitions */    
    #include <unistd.h>  /* UNIX standard function definitions */    
    #include <fcntl.h>   /* File control definitions */    
    #include <errno.h>   /* Error number definitions */    
    #include <termios.h> /* POSIX terminal control definitions */    

    /*     * 'open_port()' − Open serial port 1.     *     
    * Returns the file descriptor on success or −1 on error.     */    

   int fd; /* File descriptor for the port */

   int open_port(void)    
   {            
     fd = open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);   

     if(fd == -1) 
     {       
       /*        * Could not open the port.        */        
       perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyS0 − ");      
     }      
     else        
      fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, FNDELAY);      

    return (fd);    
  }

  int close_port(void)
  {
    close(fd);
    return (fd);
  }


  int main()
  {
    printf("Serial reader has started...\n\n");
    while(1)
    {
      open_port();
      close_port();
    }

    return 0;
  }
```

and on the RPI side, I have made a little bash script, which sends the character 1:

```
while :
do
    echo "sending character 1 to /dev/ttyS0"
    echo "1" > /dev/ttyS0
done
```

However, even though the bash script and the c program are both running in continuous loops, I am not receiving anything on the PC side.

What could be the reason?

Comment: Without further settings the virtual machine cannot connect to the USB device of the host. If you are using virt-manager you can select "Add new hardware" "USB host device" to allow the virtual machine to access the USB host device.

Comment: @Xypron
I am pretty sure it can, since I am using SSH to access the RPI from within the virtual machine.

Comment: Are you reading _/dev/ttyS0_ of host itself? What do you expect then?